# Find if a value exist in a CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fgetcsv

This is my code to check if a row of my .csv file contains a specific name, but it does not work.

I think it has something to do with the `if` statement.

```
$file_handle = fopen("sources.csv", "r");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

    if ($line_of_text[0] = 'paul') {
        echo 'Found';
    }
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

I am trying to check in sources.csv files, for the name 'Paul' .

I can't use a database like MySQL for technical reasons.

Comment: Errors if any? Plus, you're assigning with one equal sign. Do `if ($line_of_text[0] == 'paul')`

Comment: BTW `=` not the same as `==` or `===`

Comment: Show us a sample of your `.csv` file (including if it's comma seperated etc.). Finding "Paul" can be rather broad.

Comment: I think this is a good example of a question with relatively poor English (it's not terrible, but isn't great either), but is a perfectly understandable question. Kudos!

Comment: Edit your question and add a few lines of the `sources.csv` as an example of the data you are processing. BUT FIRST CHANGE `if ($line_of_text[0] = 'paul') {` to `if ($line_of_text[0] == 'paul') {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a sample of your file, am submitting the following as an alternative.

Do note that in your present code, you are assigning using a single equal sign `=` instead of comparing using `==` or `===`, *just saying as an FYI*.

`if ($line_of_text[0] = 'paul')` should read as `if ($line_of_text[0] == 'paul')`

Assuming the following `.csv` format (will work even without the commas) and is case-sensitive, consult **Footnotes** regarding case-insensitive search.

```
Paul, Larry, Robert
```

---

Code:

```
<?php
$search      = "Paul";
$lines       = file('sources.csv');
$line_number = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {

   $line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE);

}

if($line_number){

   echo "Results found for " .$search;

}

else{
   echo "No results found for $search";
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

For a case-insensitive search, use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

```
$line_number = (stripos($line, $search) !== FALSE);
```

---

***Row number found on...***

To give you the row's number where it was found:

```
$line_number = (strpos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? $count : $line_number;
```

or (case-insensitive)

```
$line_number = (stripos($line, $search) !== FALSE) ? $count : $line_number;
```

then just `echo $line_number;`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
if ($line_of_text[0] = 'paul') {
```

This will always be true because you are assigning the value `paul` to `$line_of_text[0]` with the assign operator `=`. What you want to do is check if the two are equal, so you need to use the equality operator, `==`. The line of code should be:

```
if ($line_of_text[0] == 'paul') {
```

There is also the `===` equality operator in PHP which checks for the same value AND same type. (This is a particularly nasty feature of PHP when compared to compiled languages)

e.g. consider: `$foo = 5; $bar = "5";

```
if ($foo === $bar)  // this will be false because foo is an int, and bar is a string

if ($foo == $bar) // this will be true
```

Don't be confused with the `!=` comparison operator:

```
if ($foo != $bar) // foo is not equal to bar (note the single =)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using in_array instead of ==

```
if(in_array('paul', $line_of_text)) {
  // FOUND
}
```

Comment: This is wrong because it will check ALL fields in the current CSV line, and not the desired first field.

Comment: He did not specify in the question to check only the first field. His question states: "This is my code to check if a row of my .csv file contains a specific name"  The fact that he's only checking the first field may be the problem.