# Can you read in multiple lines of CSV containing a keyword?

Tags: php, csv

I am a total newbie to php. I am wondering if it is possible to read multiple lines of csv file containing a keyword and display them in php?

I have a csv file of a following structure:

```
keyword1, data, other data, etc
keyword2, another data, other etc
keyword1, something, something etc
```

So what I would like to be printed in my php page is:

```
keyword1, data, other data, etc
keyword1, something, something etc
```

Is that possible? 
Thanks for all answers

Comment: It sure is possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate? :>

Comment: See this Q&A => http://stackoverflow.com/q/25406993/ it may be of help to you, if that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: start with fgetcsv()

Comment: Thanks Fred -ii- this should help :)

Comment: You're welcome @user57259 Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code to create html table.
Untested, so let me know if it doesn't work.

```
<?php

 $output = '<table>';
 $searchFor = "1124";

 $fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    // Read file


$matching_rows = array();

 while ( ($row = fgetcsv($fp,1000,",")) !== FALSE ) {

      // Search for keyword
      if ( (array_search( $searchFor,$row,TRUE) ) !== false ) {
           $matching_rows[] = '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>',$row) . '</td></tr>';

      }
 }
if(!empty($matching_rows) ) {
  $output = '<table><tbody>' . "\n" . implode("\n\t",$matching_rows) . "\n" . '</tbody></table>';
}

echo '<div class="display">';
echo $output;
 echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$results = array();
$handle = fopen("csvFile.csv", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if( strpos ( $data , 'keyword1' ) !== false){
        $results[] = $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `.. if $data[0] == ..`

Answer (score -1):

I found out this to be working quite well for my problem.

```
<?php

 $output = "";
 $searchFor = "1124";

 $fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    // Read file
 $txt = fgets($fp);

 while ( !feof( $fp ) ) {

      // Search for keyword
      if ( strpos( $txt, $searchFor ) !== false ) {


           $output .= $txt.'<br />';

      }

      $txt = fgets($fp);
 }
echo '<div class="display">';
 echo $output;
 echo '</div>';
?>
```

However I would be very happy if instead of coma separated values I could load these to a html table so they can look a bit nicer. I tried to concatenate $output .=$txt with table tags but only break line seems to work in this configuration. Any clues to how can I achieve this? Cheers :)