# php csv skips one line on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, csv, strpos

There seems to be some issue with the code where the result is skipped with one line.

For example, if I write: 642641
the result should be: "642641","testgatan 1"
but instead, it's showing: "762755","testgatan 2"

How can I fix so it actually get the input submitted?

I got a link for you to see what I mean: http://snaland.com/herestheidnummer/test.html

Here's the csv:

```
ID,Gata
"642641","testgatan 1"
"762755","testgatan 2"
"346468","testgatan 3"
"114564","testgatan 4"
"758925","testgatan 5"
```

I used the php code from [Find if a value exist in a CSV file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406993/find-if-a-value-exist-in-a-csv-file-with-php) by Fred -ii-

And modified it like this:

```
<?php
$search      = $_GET['subject'];
$lines       = file('http://snaland.com/herestheidnummer/anlaggningsnmr.csv');
$line_number = false;

while (list($key, $line) = each($lines) and !$line_number) {
   $line_number = (stripos($line, $search) !== FALSE);

}

if($line_number){

   echo "Found result: " .$line;

}

else{
   echo "Can't find result: " .$search;
}

?>
```

Html form:

```
<form name="form" action="http://snaland.com/herestheidnummer/verifiera.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="000000">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the condition in the while loop. The assignment to key and list get executed before the check of !$line_number. It should work ff you swap both conditions like this

```
while (!$line_number and list($key, $line) = each($lines) ) {
   $line_number = (stripos($line, $search) !== FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. It worked, appreciated the help :)
i can't + vote your answer because of bad posts before this, actually because of dyslexia, hopefully someone else can upvote.

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Each advances the array cursor, so when you finde the result, the next value is already loaded. More here  http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php.

A simpler solution is to replace your loop with:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($lines);$i++){
if(stripos($lines[$i], $search) !== false){
    $line = $lines[$i];
        break;
    }
}
```

And on the if:

```
if($line){

   echo "Found result: " .$line;

}
```